# ASP.NET MVC. Application not running

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

Today it was working correctly. Now I am trying to run app, but browser (Chrome) tab loading sign is going round and round with message "Loading...". Waited for 30mins - no change. App is running on this url (if this can help this problem) - localhost:12581. IIS Express is listing app. And when I tried to stop, it took long time, but it managed to stop. Visual Studio is giving following output:

> 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll' 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'
>   A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\03256081\21bfe13d_5a56d001\Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll' 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WebMatrix.WebData\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WebMatrix.WebData.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\b7b64074\7028793d_5a56d001\System.Web.Optimization.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\4f42525f\d1731d3d_5a56d001\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Razor.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\540a4573\afa4863e_5a56d001\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll'
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll iisexpress.exe Information: 0 :
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246 (official) A first chance exception of
>   type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Reporting will use
>   isolated storage with scope: User, Domain, Assembly 'iisexpress.exe'
>   (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WebMatrix.Data\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WebMatrix.Data.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. The thread '' (0x8d4) has exited with code 0
>   (0x0). The thread '' (0x13ec) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.resources.dll'
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. The thread '' (0x2d4) has exited with code 0
>   (0x0). The thread '' (0x3e0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. The thread '' (0x94) has exited with code 0
>   (0x0). 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. The thread '' (0x380) has exited with code 0
>   (0x0). 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. The thread '' (0x2d4) has exited with code 0
>   (0x0). The thread '' (0x11d8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll', Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. The thread '' (0xbc8) has exited with code 0
>   (0x0). The thread '' (0xaf0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\5ec36bb3\9639f73f_5a56d001\Antlr3.Runtime.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\29286995\ed404e3e_5a56d001\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\0d4d18c7\5a10ee3e_5a56d001\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\d65ffc97\09ea3c3f_5a56d001\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\4767d151\0d466e3f_5a56d001\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\c6981479\1d9da73f_5a56d001\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\88fc42b3\983c5630_5a56d001\EntityFramework.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\f1c5191e\9fdf043b_5a56d001\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\8e74a503\aab0801c_6656d001\NotTorg.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\daf18e22\3fa9663c_5a56d001\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Helpers\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Helpers.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\f1cf004b\fbdae13c_5a56d001\System.Web.Http.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\assembly\dl3\918b817c\0f890240_5a56d001\WebGrease.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Design.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089\System.resources.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bb8b00a8\6cf9ea94\App_global.asax.ggbp6b9x.dll', Symbols
>   loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. The thread '' (0xadc) has exited with code 0
>   (0x0). The thread '' (0xbfc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Entity.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.Hosting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Xaml.Hosting.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Framework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll', Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Workflow.ComponentModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Workflow.ComponentModel.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Workflow.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Workflow.Activities.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Workflow.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Workflow.Runtime.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. The program '[3412] iisexpress.exe: Managed
>   (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0). The program '[3412]
>   iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

What could be a problem? How to solve this problem?

Comment: We don't need all that diagnostic info. Just the error message and stack trace and relevant code. Look at the errors tab in VS. You'll see something about `CultureNotFoundException`. Please edit your question to only include the info I described.

Comment: there is no any error in Error List

Comment: There are a few exceptions in the diagnostic, not just a CultureNotFound. I think this is a red herring. Sometimes IIS Express gets weird. Stupid question, did you try restarting VisualStudio to see if this fixes it?

Comment: dustinmoris, tried to restart VS, even Windows, no change

Comment: Do a Control-Shift-B to rebuild your project and see if any errors appear in the Error List.

Comment: mason, there is no any error. But I changed compilation debug="true" to compilation debug="false". Now app is working, is this can be cause for this problem?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you ever get this figured out? I know that switching to regular iis instead of express could fix it and downgrading to iis express 8 will fix it, but I was curious if you found a different solution.